# Loading Jquery externally from CDN causes many issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cdn

I am using rails with Jquery and the jquery-ujs adapter. When I remove jquery from my application and instead load it in through a CDN, i experience many javascript issues in my code. For example, the spinjs-rails is causing ajax requests to fail, however, when jquery is instead included in the asset pipeline, this issue is doesn't occur. This is not the only issue I am experiencing.

Why does loading the jquery externally from a CDN make a difference?

I am using the google jquery CDN and the jquery version is the same.

Update:

I was formely using the jquery-rails gem for both jquery and jquery_ujs, I have stopped using the jquery part of this in favour of the google jquery CDN. However, even when I load the jquery locally (without using the jquery provided by the jquery-rails gem), I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Please paste the script part of your page's html.

Answer (score 0):

possible reason

1. check the version of jquery you are using from CDN.
2. Check whether file is avaliable on CDN.

Comment: The version is the same, and I am using the google CDN, so the file is available.